# Delete FontAwesome from my Xcode project Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, font-awesome

I downloaded and install FontAwesome for Swift (https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift) via Pods and i'd like to remove it completely from my project but I don't find any solutions and when I remove the file one by one I get an error :

> could not read data from '/Users/[...]/Pods/Target Support Files/FontAwesome.swift/ResourceBundle-FontAwesome.swift-Info.plist': The file “ResourceBundle-FontAwesome.swift-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a pod, simply remove the corresponding line from your Podfile (in your case: `pod 'FontAwesome.swift'`) and run `pod install` or `pod update`.